# How to determine the MU in economics?

Tags: economics

I currently have a table like so:

Hours spent on Activity X | Total Utility

> 1. 120
> 2. 220
> 3. 300
> 4. 360
> 5. 396
> 6. 412

I know that Marginal Utility is calculated use slope formulate (delta Y / delta X).
I am asked to calculate the MU for 5 hours:
So in this case, $delta X = 5 - 1 = 4$ and $deltaY = 396 - 120 = 276$
Then, MU = $deltaY/deltaX = 276/4 = 69$

Next I am supposed to calculate the MU per dollar, which is determined by:
$deltaY/deltaX * 1/Price$ . The question states the price of activity X is $5/hour.

Then, I would have $MU per dollar = 69/5 = 13.8$ This gives me 13.8 dollars as the MU per dollar, however, the answer to this question is 7.2 dollars. Can anyone please explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Your title is not informative.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my title.

Comment: I liked the previous title anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are calculating MU wrong
$$\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X}=\frac{Y_5-Y_4}{X_5-X_4}=\frac{396-360}{5-4}=36$$
$$\Rightarrow \text{MU}_\text{per dollar}=36/5=7.2$$

Comment: I think @oxFF says he/she is "asked to calculate the MU for 5 hours." But in my opinion this answer is for the fifth hour, not for the entire five hours?

Comment: In economics marginals are instantenous changes. If OP would have asked for five hours OP would have said "average".